# How can I order by more fields in WP woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to order by two fields my products. I need a default order by '_sku' and if user selects for exemple 'date', it have to order by 'date' and '_sku'. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');

function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {

// $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
$args['meta_key'] = array('_sku',$SESSION['orderby']);

 $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
 $args['order'] = 'asc'; 

 return $args;
}
```

My output error:

```
trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in (File and myLine)
```

And I dont know if I need to filter $SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

is this session retorning the value of the orderby?